# Couldn't install php55 by brew, tried all the possible solutions

Tags: php, macos, installation, homebrew

I had pre-installed php 5.4.24 when I bought my mac. Then with Brew I installed php 5.5.8 which was working fine. Yesterday, I wanted to install php 5.2 which I started via brew install php52. It gave issue-

1) Configure error: freetype.h not found
After I fixed that I had another issue-

2) configure: error: GD build test failed. Please check the config.log for details.

Then I realised I was not able to run php 5.5.8 that I had installed before. I uninstalled it and then while re-installing: brew install php55, I had the issue:
configure: error: GD build test failed. Please check the config.log for details.

I tried all the possible things:

1) Ran brew docor.

2) brew upgrade && brew update.

3) rm freetype zlib gd .....

4) brew install freetype zlib gd

5) Linking all of them properly.

I am not able to proceed. Please Help.
Please dont ask me to do via macports or MAMP.

config.log->

```
`$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.11 --localstatedir=/usr/local/var --sysconfdir=/usr/local/etc/php/5.5 --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/etc/php/5.5 --with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d --with-iconv-dir=/usr --enable-dba --with-ndbm=/usr --enable-exif --enable-soap --enable-wddx --enable-ftp --enable-sockets --enable-zip --enable-shmop --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-sysvmsg --enable-mbstring --enable-mbregex --enable-bcmath --enable-calendar --with-zlib=/usr/local/opt/zlib --with-ldap --with-ldap-sasl=/usr --with-xmlrpc --with-kerberos=/usr --with-gd --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/opt/freetype --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/opt/jpeg --with-png-dir=/usr/local/opt/libpng --with-gettext=/usr/local/opt/gettext --with-snmp=/usr --with-libedit --with-unixODBC=/usr/local/opt/unixodbc --with-pdo-odbc=unixODBC,/usr/local/opt/unixodbc --mandir=/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.11/share/man --with-mhash --with-curl --with-bz2=/usr --disable-debug --with-openssl=/usr --with-xsl=/usr --with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs --libexecdir=/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.11/libexec --with-mysql-sock=/tmp/mysql.sock --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-mysql=mysqlnd --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd --enable-pcntl --enable-zend-signals --enable-dtrace --enable-opcache

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = Subham-Khandelwal.local
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 13.1.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 13.1.0: Thu Jan 16 19:40:37 PST 2014; root:xnu-2422.90.20~2/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
         Darwin Kernel Version 13.1.0: Thu Jan 16 19:40:37 PST 2014; root:xnu-2422.90.20~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 4 processors.
2 processors are physically available.
4 processors are logically available.
Processor type: i486 (Intel 80486)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3
Primary memory available: 8.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 218 tasks, 1116 threads, 4 processors
Load average: 4.00, Mach factor: 0.93
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3
PATH: /usr/local/opt/libpng/bin
PATH: /usr/local/opt/freetype/bin
PATH: /usr/local/opt/gettext/bin
PATH: /usr/local/opt/jpeg/bin
PATH: /usr/local/opt/unixodbc/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin

## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##
::
::
configure:4184: result: yes
configure:4193: checking whether clang accepts -g
configure:4213: clang -c -g  conftest.c >&5
configure:4213: $? = 0
configure:4254: result: yes
configure:4271: checking for clang option to accept ISO C89
configure:4334: clang  -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:4334: $? = 0
configure:4347: result: none needed
configure:4373: checking how to run the C preprocessor
configure:4404: clang -E  conftest.c
configure:4404: $? = 0
configure:4418: clang -E  conftest.c
conftest.c:9:10: fatal error: 'ac_nonexistent.h' file not found
#include <ac_nonexistent.h>


1 error generated.
configure:4418: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
configure:4443: result: clang -E
configure:4463: clang -E  conftest.c
configure:4463: $? = 0
configure:4477: clang -E  conftest.c
conftest.c:9:10: fatal error: 'ac_nonexistent.h' file not found
#include <ac_nonexistent.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
configure:4477: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */

| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""

| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""

| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""

| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""

| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""

| #define PACKAGE_URL ""

| /* end confdefs.h.  */

| #include <ac_nonexistent.h>

configure:4508: checking for icc

configure:4517: result: no
::
::
conftest.c:52:10: fatal error: 'minix/config.h' file not found
#include <minix/config.h>

conftest.c:58:10: fatal error: 'sys/pstat.h' file not found
#include <sys/pstat.h>

::
configure:10853: clang -o conftest -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden  -no-cpp-precomp  conftest.c  >&5

conftest.c:26:10: fatal error: 'sys/exec.h' file not found

include <sys/exec.h>`
```

Comment: and what does `config.log` said ?

Comment: I don't know where it is, can you tell me the location of config.log?

Comment: `~/Library/Logs/Homebrew/config.log.<formula>.<timestamp>` ?

Comment: @Samoth I have added my log file above please have a look.. Thanks..

Comment: And may I ask which version of OS X you're running on?

Comment: OS X: 10.9.2  
Xcode: 5.1  
Command line tool: 5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wasted lot of time at last I removed Brew entirely and re-installed. Took hardly half an hour to fix all the dependencies. Everything is working now. :)

Answer (score 0):

it seem to be a php bug:

You can fix your configure by removing -L$GD_LIB on line 42415:

-LIBS=" -L$GD_LIB $GD_SHARED_LIBADD  $LIBS"
+LIBS=" $GD_SHARED_LIBADD  $LIBS"

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41555

Answer (score 0):

After running into a similar error I discovered installing the xcode command line tools resolved the error.

Run the following in terminal to install:
xcode-select --install